# pgfplotstable: postproc cell content resets style of cell

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm using pgfplotstable to create tables from .csv-files. But when I use `postproc cell content` to change the appearence of a specific cell, all former formatting of this cell seems to be ignored. How can I make changes to the appearence of a specific cell and at the same time preserve a uniform styling of the table?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%Make rows higher:
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.4pt}

%GLOBAL FORMATING:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
                use comma,
                1000 sep={}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Name,1,2
A,10.23,3.23
B,11.23,4.23
C,12.23,5.23
D,13.23,6.23
E,14.23,7.23
F,15.23,8.23
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Some text describing the table}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    columns={Name, 1, 2},% <---these columns will appear in the table
%------------------TYPESETTING COLUMNS:-------------------------------
     columns/Name/.style={% <---style column "Name"
      string type,%
      column type/.add={}{|},%
    },
    %
    columns/1/.style={% <---style column "1"
      column name=I,
      precision=1,column type/.add={}{|},%
    },
    %
    columns/2/.style={% <---style column "2"
      column name=II,
      precision=1, column type/.add={}{},%
      postproc cell content/.code={% <--- style row 2 (=index 1) of column "2"
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1 
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\textcolor{red!100}{##1}}% <---make it red
        \fi
      },
    },
    %
%------------------TYPESETTING ROWS-------------------------------
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},%
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}%
    ]%
{data.csv}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]



\end{document}
```

And this is, what it looks like:

[image: Obviously the formatting of the red cell differs from the others.]

I would like to have the cell containing `4.23` to contain `4,2`, so that it is formatted as all the other cells.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `##1` is a shortcut to the value `@preprocessed cell content`. In this context you need `@cell content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible (but I guess not the best) solution:

```
  postproc cell content/.append code={% <--- style row 2 (=index 1) of
      \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1\relax% 
          \edef\temp{%
              \noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
                  {\noexpand\color{red!100}\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}}%
          }\temp%
      \fi%
  }
```

[image]

**Update:**

Using bold font instead of changing the text color (to highlight the cell) is easier:

```
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1\relax% 
      \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}
  \fi%
```

Comment: Looks pretty OK to me.

Comment: @percusse A lot of low level code just to change the text color?

Comment: Haha that's acceptable criticism I guess. But this is rather a lot of low level code for table automation. Imagine you have 50 rows and you look for the minimum etc. then it will pay off.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as desired. Could I change the cell to bold text with this approach too? I'm sorry, but I really have no clue of how `\edef`,`\expandafter` and `\noexpand` work. And if I just replace `\color{red!100}` with something else, it only works for things like `\tiny` etc.

Comment: @Wamseln Add `\noexpand\boldmath` before `\noexpand\color`

Comment: Thank you! This works as desired. The only thing left for me to figure out is, how to change the font of a cell while preserving its former formatting. Do you have an idea of how to do that?